# Create Historical Data

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to prepare historical data from startdate to end date (30-04-2020). Start Date is different as per User. End date remains same for all users (30-04-2020).

```
data <- read.table(text = "User  StartDate
1     24-04-2019
2     31-07-2019
3     2015-10-27", header = TRUE)
```

**Desired Output - Every date should have last day of the month from startdate to end date for each user**

```
User ID DesiredDate
1   4/30/2019
1   5/31/2019
1   6/30/2019
1   7/31/2019
1   8/31/2019
1   9/30/2019
1   10/31/2019
1   11/30/2019
1   12/31/2019
1   1/31/2020
1   2/29/2020
1   3/31/2020
1   4/30/2020
```

Comment: Can you specify your problem? What is the question? What did you already try? Is the problem in the formatting of the input dates ("dd-mm-yyy" vs "yyy-mm-dd")?

Comment: problem is creating historical data.

Comment: Your comment does not really make the question clearer, please show some effort when commenting. What do you mean by historical data? I suppose you want to create a vector/list with sequence of dates with different starting points and constant endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential solution using `lubridate` and `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  mutate(date1 = dmy(StartDate),
         date2 = ymd(StartDate),
         StartDate = coalesce(date1,date2),
         StartDate = -1 + ceiling_date(StartDate, unit = 'month'),
         EndDate = ymd(c("2020-04-30"))) %>% 
  select(User, StartDate, EndDate) %>% 
  group_by(User) %>% 
  transmute(User, DesiredDate = map2(StartDate, EndDate, seq, by = "1 month")) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  mutate(DesiredDate = -1 + ceiling_date(DesiredDate, unit = 'month'))
```

Which gives us:

```
  User DesiredDate
   <int> <date>     
 1     1 2019-04-30 
 2     1 2019-05-31 
 3     1 2019-06-30 
 4     1 2019-07-31 
 5     1 2019-08-31 
 6     1 2019-09-30 
 7     1 2019-10-31 
 8     1 2019-11-30 
 9     1 2019-12-31 
10     1 2020-01-31 
11     1 2020-03-31 
12     1 2020-03-31 
13     1 2020-04-30 
14     2 2019-07-31 
15     2 2019-08-31 
16     2 2019-10-31 
17     2 2019-10-31 
18     2 2019-12-31 
19     2 2019-12-31 
20     2 2020-01-31
```

Comment: I added more clarity - I need historical date to be created for each user from start date to end date. In every date it should be last day of the month (refer desired output)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#Data
data <- structure(list(User = 1:3, StartDate = c("24-04-2019", "31-07-2019", 
"27-10-2015")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
structure(list(User = 1:3, StartDate = c("24-04-2019", "31-07-2019", 
"27-10-2015")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

#Create list by id
List <- split(data,data$User)
#Endpoint
endpoint <- as.Date('30-04-2020','%d-%m-%Y')
#Build function for sequences
builddata <- function(x)
{
  val1 <- x$User
  valstart <- as.Date(x$StartDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
  seqdate <- seq(valstart,endpoint,by='1 day') 
  datadates <- data.frame(User=rep(val1,length(seqdate)),Date=seqdate,stringsAsFactors = F)
  return(datadates)
}
#Apply function
List <- lapply(List,builddata)
#Bind all
df <- do.call(rbind,List)
rownames(df)<-NULL
```

You will end up with a dataframe of `2296` rows and `2` columns. I include some rows:

```
  User       Date
1    1 2019-04-24
2    1 2019-04-25
3    1 2019-04-26
4    1 2019-04-27
5    1 2019-04-28
6    1 2019-04-29
```